# Git and SVN and no history

Tags: git, svn

I have a problem.

I use Git with a SVN repository. But some people change the SVN repository (they create a new repository a just put in it all files of project). They don't save the SVN history of the old repository.

I don't know how to hook up Git with the new SVN repository in order to commit my modifications.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Finally I have found a solution.

So I have a local repository Git (in my local directory /home/oldSVNrepo) which is hooked up to the old SVN repository. There are no common commits between the old and new SVN repository.

What I must do:

I must commit my modifications in the new SVN repository

What I do:

1 - I create a local directory (like mkdir /tmp/myNewRepo )
2 - In this new directory, I clone the new SVN repository

> `cd /tmp/myNewRepo
>   git svn clone [UrlOfNewSVNrepository]/myproject -T trunk -b branches -t tags --username XXX
>   cd myproject
>   git checkout -b dev
>   git checkout master`

I create a new branch in order to merge new update for the SVN repository and in order to push from remote repository commits. (We can't push on repo if the branch is active)

3 - In my local Git repository of the OLD SVN, I add a remote repository: the new Git repository

> `
>       cd /home/oldSVNrepo
>       git remote add neworigin -t dev /tmp/myNewRepo/myproject

4 - I fetch data from the remote repository

```
git fetch neworigin/dev
```

5 - I create a new branch (before I commit all modifications) in my old Git repository

> `git checkout -b branchForMerge`

6 - I do merge between the remote neworigin and branchForMerge

> `git merge neworigin/dev`

When I do the merge, Git give me a warning: no common commit.
(In fact, in my case, i use git-mv before merge, because the old directory of myproject is different of the new project directory)

7 - I fix conflicts and commit

8 - I push my modifications on neworigin

> `git push neworigin branchForMerge:dev`

9 - And now on branch dev of new Git repository (/tmp/myNewRepo), I can easly send my modifications on the new SVN repository

So i just create a new local Git repository which hooks up to the new SVN repository and add a remote branch in my old Git repository in order to transfer my local commits. I don't know if it's a good solution but it works for me.

Thanks Git

Thanks Zeeker

Comment: You could try to modificate your `git-svn` repository configuration (you can find them in `.git/config` in your repository) and change the URL to match the URL of the new repository, but I can not guarantee that this works and won't blow up your own repository. If you want to try this, make sure that you make a backup of your repo first.

Comment: Thanks Zeeker. In fact i already do that. It doesn't work because the history of the new repository is different of the old. When i do a rebase i have this error: Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a second svn remote in your git repository by editing the `config` file in your `<repository>/.git` folder.

It could look like this (with the second being the new repository):

```
...
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://url.to.the.first.svn.repository
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[svn-remote "new-svn"]
        url = https://url.to.the.second.svn.repository
        fetch = :refs/remotes/new-git-svn
...
```

You can fetch the new repository `git svn fetch new-svn`; this should result in the remote branch `new-git-svn` being up to date with the new repository.
Now you should be easily able to `rebase` your own modifications onto the new `new-git-svn`, so you can commit them to the repository.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I try but i have two problems with this solution. The first when i do the svn-fecth, Git says me there is two svn remote repository. I must to delete the old repo in order to fecth the new repository (I use Git 1.7.9 on Cygwin). The second problem when i do the rebase i have this error:Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history. There are no common commits between the new and old repository